# Modelling plane with irregular corner radius - how to model this shape?

Tags: modeling

I'm struggling to figure out how to create the following shape without ending up with loads of triangles or shading problems. I've tried using an extruded SVG, which is fine for a flat plane, but ill need to make an extrusion and spin the lower edge at some point, which means converting to a mesh, however the resulting mesh is really untidy.

IF the corner radius(es?) were all the same number of vertices that would be fine, I could model that, but the different corners are posing a real problem to me!

To summarise - how does one go about creating a mesh for the following shape?

Many thanks in advance :)

[image: rad]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to do it, tell me if it's ok:

[image]

Comment: Thank you - That looks much better than what I managed! Mind sharing what the workflow is like to create this?

Comment: @moonboots placing the text as part of the image makes the answer inaccessible to search engines.

Comment: is it not the question that is important for a search engine? By the way, how long will stackexchange keep the pictures in its servers?

Comment: They're hosted on imgur forever (in theory).