# Need help to recreate this shape in blender

Tags: modeling

Could somebody here please help me make this 3d shape in blender. I have been struggling with this. There is a hollow cutout in the middle of the card.

[image]

Comment: do you want that white part as a whole in that square/rectangle?

Comment: Check out this question here:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/130958/modelling-plane-with-irregular-corner-radius-how-to-model-this-shape. It's basically the same shape, just with one flat side. If you make both corners rounded instead it will give you what you want.

Comment: @Yash, yes exactly, the white part in the middle should be hollow.

Comment: ok I am answering..

Answer (score 1):

Use **Boolean modifier** to do such Hollows in Mesh:

### See how it woks:

You can do these on Default cube when Blender is Opened with Default Settings.
Just add two modifiers:
1. Bevel:
[image]

Add Subdivision Surface(Subsurf) Modifier..
And change the view and render both to 3.
[image]
Scale it according to your object by pressing <kbd>S</kbd>. If you want to scale your object particularly on one axis (after pressing <kbd>S</kbd>)press<kbd>X</kbd>/<kbd>Y</kbd>/<kbd>Z</kbd> respectively.
[image]
Now Duplicate your object by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and press<kbd>Y</kbd> to move it only on Y axis.
[image]
Now scale the **Duplicated cube** down to Z axis, it depends on how much you wish the hollow size to be.Make sure you scale more on X axis to make whole visible from outside of the actual cube.
[image]
Now take the duplicated cube and move it inside the Actual cube by moving it on Y axis.(Press<kbd>G</kbd>and<kbd>Y</kbd>)
[image]

> Now this is important.

Select the **Actual cube** and add Boolean modifier to it.
[image]
Go to Boolean Modifier Settings and select the duplicated cube. There's only one so it will show it only one. Select it.
[image]
Edit:
Click on the drop down in side of the selection:
Change it from Intersect to Difference.
[image]
Now apply the Boolean modifier of the **Actual cube**.
[image]
Now you can delete the duplicated cube you will see the Hollow in the cube.
[image]
You are done.

> If Bevel and Subsurface Modifiers don't work well for your mesh, you
>   can just go to Edit Mode, Press A if your mesh is  not selected and
>   Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and scroll Mouse
>   wheel to make changes, you will notice some changes in corners of your
>   Cube, Plane,etc. It works same as the combination of Bevel and Subsurface Modifiers

Check out this [Boolean.blend](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WSnP2vzYaNx4nWCht00kwqk1bSkD053y) file.
Check Modifiers Stack.

> It is not necessary to duplicate and hollow, you can add any object
>   like UV Sphere and do the same. But now UV sphere will act as
>   Duplicated cube.  Imp: Add Boolean Modifier only to the object you
>   want to hollow. Not which you are using to Hollow.

Happy Modelling!

Comment: Thanks, I was able to cut a hole into my object but how do you round the corners like that? My object does not need to be extruded so much, it's pretty much a flat, rectangular plane with very small amount of extrusion. Could you provide me with a blender file so I can play with it? I'm new to this.

Comment: Yes why not wait I am linking it in my answer.

Comment: This is what I have now. Sorry how do I show you a screen shot in the comment?

Comment: Add your picture to file hosting site like Google Drive and share the link in comment

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/FHW3Yv9w/image.png

Comment: I think you have missed Bevel modifier. It helps increasing width of edges.

Comment: I can't open the file, it seems like you are working on a beta version. I am on 2.79b

Comment: I have already tried adding the bevel modifier to my object but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Ok I am posting another file for 2.79.

Comment: I think you should link your .blend file here.

Comment: okay let me do that, hold on... If you can please open my file and make the edges round exactly like the very 1st image I posted. That would really help me.

Comment: Okay Let's see..

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rmLXNFOhxoBMgAWsshPZAa8ktKKe6DYV

Comment: It looks like you added a plane and increased the width. I played with some settings in bevel and it is fixed, I changed from Offset to Percent and increased the width of Bevel in its Modifier settings. See this - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BxNWGC429GDTA29QkaFzKJcGVb6q7DyK

Comment: That looks good, but can you do the cut out in the middle with the same rounded corners as well. I changed the bevel modifier width metho from percent to depth because I don't like the small lip at the bottom of the plane.

Comment: I made it like yours, see now - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1w8JKhJt-StwhuCjWNeqlJPU3hWOJB8uI , but before you apply boolean modifier, apply subdivision and bevel modifiers, beacause applying it before them may ruin your mesh. You can try applying them before it to see how it ruins.

Comment: That is the same file, the middle part isn't cut out.

Comment: Oh sorry my apologies, try https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hjQI0nvjOJv64c-aRWJO0ttJdjAj52fm

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. But what is this wireframe thing in the middle and how do I get rid of it?

Comment: Whatever that wireframe thing in the middle is, it's lagging blender and makes it unresponsive. :(

Comment: Thats the object which is creating the hollow, that duplicate object that I mentioned in my answer. I made it to display as wire to see the hollow without applying the boolean modifier, after you apply boolean modifier, you can delete that or if you want too see how I made it to see as wire, select that object go to Object data panel and change it to textured. see - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SrSAgdcW3TLF_TeJddULlEork381fKlI/view?usp=sharing.

Comment: Where is the object data panel?

Comment: If selecting it makes your blender unresponsive, select it from Outliner - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H9gkGuClF47g6RIUIvZagJ1gM6sT6gg1/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I mean, I know how to select it, but how do I change it to textured?

Comment: Click on the dropdown where it is written "Wire" and change it to texture

Comment: Sorry but I don't see where that is.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SrSAgdcW3TLF_TeJddULlEork381fKlI/view?usp=sharing.

Comment: I edited my comment previously but you didn't notice it..

Comment: Oops, sorry, see it now. Let me try again. :)

Comment: So I did like you said and applied subdivision and bevel modifier 1st and this is what happens - https://i.postimg.cc/90KjnrVy/image.png I haven't applied the bevel modifier yet.

Comment: You were suppose to apply modifiers to the plane to which you need the hollow.

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong - https://i.postimg.cc/85d2btnQ/image.png

Comment: I think I got it, could you tell me how I can adjust the rounded corners, I want the shape to be more like the original picture that I posted. The curve in this one is not the same. - https://i.postimg.cc/mZvX80Fv/image.png

Comment: You have applied modifiers now, you can't change it now!

Comment: :( So I have to start all over now? I wish I can readjust the corners somehow.

Comment: Now Loop cuts will help you tighten your edges at some point.

Comment: I found an easier way to do this. 1st create a flat plane... and then SHIFT-CTRL-B while using scroll wheel to adjust the corners. And then Extrude last. No need for beveling.

Comment: Where did you find these technique, anyways I tried and it is awesome, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: I just did a search on duckduckgo. :) This method is much easier.

Comment: Forget about bevel now, I am up to this new method.

Comment: hahaha glad it helped you out too! :)

Comment: @Amanda Please add your solution as a separate answer to this question.

Comment: @Leander she does not have the answer,she was satisfied with the answer I provided, she just found to replace bevel modifier to a shortcut key.

Comment: The other method uses a different operation, happens in edit mode only, doesn't use modifiers and uses only a single object. It is a different method could be beneficial for other users, if it was added as a separate answer.

Comment: May I edit it to my answer? @Leander

Comment: Sure, it would fit well as a 2nd method. You could also add another answer. It's just that valuable information shouldn't be left in the comments only, as they are temporary and don't show up in the search results.

Comment: @Leander as you say!